# Accessing list array generated by for loop in range Python 3.5

Tags: python, list

For a small project battleship py3.5:

```
def maingame_sp():

    global board
    board = [['.' for i in range (0,10)] \
                  for j in range (0,10)]

def coordinates(board):
    x_ax = input(str("Give coordinate x"))

    y_ax = input(int("Give coordinate y"))
```

I am trying to build a version of battleship where I can input coordinates like A1 to the board and replacing the "." with a marker for misses and hits.

Can anyone give me a little help on how to access multiple lists inside a lists generated by the forloop range to replace an item using the input x- and y-axis?

Comment: Is `A` in `A1` part of the *x* or the *y*-axis?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question needs a few changes to become acceptable. First, show what have you tried. Second, your question needs to be more clear. Do you want the input to be the coordinates in numbers, line `x_ax` and `y_ax` as in your code, or like `A1` as in your text?

Comment: I was trying to figure out how i input coordinates like A1, how i do this i really dont know so i was hoping the community could help me point me in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do it like this:

```
def maingame_sp():

    global board
    board = [['.' for i in range (0,10)] \
                  for j in range (0,10)]

def coordinates(board):
    x_ax = input(str("Give coordinate x"))
    y_ax = input(int("Give coordinate y"))

    try:
        board[ord(x_ax)-ord('A')][ord(y_ax)-1] = "-"
    except IndexError:
        print("Wrong input")
```

If the axis are printing the wrong way, swap the square-brakets order:

```
        board[ord(y_ax)-1][ord(x_ax)-ord('A')] = "-"
```

Comment: Thx for sharing !

Answer (score 0):

if i understand, you want access to a cell in a 2d array.
`>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', ['1', '2']]`
`>>> a[3][1]`
 `'2'`
`

Comment: Ah, i think i should be able to slam something together. What i do not fully understand however, how the list looks like from the printed array, is it like 1 list with 10 list inside it, to print a 10x10 grid ? So accessing J10 would be index 10/10 if im correct. ( x and y coordinates are printed at index -1 on the list )

Comment: for a grid who start at A1 and end at J10, A1 is at `board[0][0]` and J10 is at `board[9][9]`